# OpAmp openloop threshold between inputs

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog

I have read about OpAmps in openloop configuration where thy output +V,0,-V depending on the inputs.

when the inputs are equal, the output should be 0. My question is, what can be the threshold or difference of inputs so they get evaluated as equal?

For example if pos input is 0.0001V and the neg input is 0.0002V will I get 0V? I think it is not that sensitive...the question is what in the datasheet of the opamp I should look to find this number? what properties affect this?

[image]

Comment: It isn't a digital threshold.  It's a noisy, analog, squishy thing that depends on the open loop gain, the inherent noise of the circuit, stray impedances and capacitances, the phase of the moon, and your girlfriend's mood.

Comment: @JRE well I get your point :) so you mean there is nothing that can be calculated here I guess? so the inputs can be 1V and 2V but I still get 0?... I mean there should be some point that it works as intended...how to know that point?

Comment: The circuit may even oscillate, because Electric field feedback, or because of feedback by the power supply, or because of thermal feedback where the opamp output transistors heat up and that heat flows along the silicon to the input differential pair transistors where the slightly-imbalanced heat flows cause imbalance in the two transistors and the open-loop-gain converts that into 1 or 5 volts output changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the question is what in the datasheet of the opamp I should look to
>   find this number?

The open-loop gain of an op-amp at DC can be in the region of 100,000 to 10,000,000. In other words, you need a difference of much less than 0.1 uV to 10 uV to create theoretically zero volts at your output.

However, given that most op-amps might have an input offset voltage of between +/-10 uV to +/-10 mV (an error quantity), it's nonesensical to try and create zero volts at the output by considering the open-loop gain.

It's also nonesensical to try and do this by considering the input offset error because this is somewhat dependent on temperature and a 1 degree centrigrade change might make a 1 uV to 10 uV change in the offset error and lead to 0 volts on the output rapidly hitting the end stops of the power rails.